# Debugging Expo React Native iOS in JetBrains WebStorm (2023.2.4 MacOS)

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to debug a very basic Expo (latest SDK 49) React Native app in WebStorm (2023/MacOS) on iOS simulator but breakpoints just do not work.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with my configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]